# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException using SAXParser, InputStream, XMLHandler

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, wbxml

I am trying to convert xml into wbxml to pass information from a fake device ( iPhone, Android, Blackberry, etc. ) to a server that knows the request I am sending.  I am receiving a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException on this line of code:

xr.parse(new InputSource(in));

I also added this code to my project to try and do the conversion:
http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/source/browse/k9mail/branches/activesync/src/com/android/email/mail/internet/WBXML.java?r=403

You can see the comments note that an xml stream needs passed in as a parameter.  I do that in the code below.

"    /**
     * Converts an XML input stream to a WBXML output stream
     *
     * @param in  The XML stream to read from
     * @param out The WBXML stream to write to
     */
"

I do not know much about "CodePage" and this could be a problem in how I am using it by putting a '1' when I initialize the array for "CodePage".  I do not know what to put there.    I do know that if I take the number "1" out, then Eclipse complains that I need to provide a dimensions expression or initialize the array.  So, maybe that is where the stringindexoutofboundsexception comes from, but just does not show up until later.  Anyways, I also tried 1000 to initialize the CodePage array and that did not help as well.

CodePage[] codePage = new CodePage[ 1000 ];

I know also that this is probably a little more complicated of an issue and I cannot just post my whole project here.  I thank anyone in advanced that provides help.  Even if it is just in a general sense to help pin this down, it's much appreciated.

======================  Here is the relevant code from that link for this issue ===========

File 1:

```
    File file19 = new File("data\\test.xml");
    InputStream is19 = new FileInputStream(file19);
    CodePage[] codePage = new CodePage[ 1 ];  // also tried 1000 here and made no difference, didn't help
    WBXMLClass wbxmlObject = new WBXMLClass( codePage );
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream19 = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );
    wbxmlObject.convertXmlToWbxml(is19, byteArrayOutputStream19 );
```

File 2

```
 public void convertXmlToWbxml(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {

    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        XMLHandler handler = new XMLHandler(out);

        xr.setContentHandler(handler);

        xr.parse(new InputSource(in));  // this is causing string index out of bounds ****************************
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        //Log.e("WBXML", "ParserConfigurationException in convertXmlToWbxml: " + pce);
    } catch (SAXException se) {
        //Log.e("WBXML", "SAXException in convertXmlToWbxml: " + se);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        //Log.e("WBXML", "IOException in convertXmlToWbxml: " + ioe);
    }
}
```

=====================================

Here is the error in Eclipse:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at tags.WBXMLClass$XMLHandler.startElement(WBXMLClass.java:447)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at tags.WBXMLClass.convertXmlToWbxml(WBXMLClass.java:370)
    at Test.main(Test.java:452)

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Test [Java Application] 
 Test at localhost:28099 
  Thread [main] (Suspended (exception StringIndexOutOfBoundsException)) 
   XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration(XML11Configuration).parse(XMLInputSource) line: not available 
   SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser(XMLParser).parse(XMLInputSource) line: not available 
   SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser(AbstractSAXParser).parse(InputSource) line: not available 
   SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(InputSource) line: not available 
   WBXMLClass.convertXmlToWbxml(InputStream, OutputStream) line: 371 
   Test.main(String[]) line: 459

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not know much about "CodePage"

This is not about the CodePage. This is about the arrays and array dimensions. But your exception does not rely on this.

**UPDATE1**
Ok, I think that problem is here:

447 line in your [WBXML.java](https://code.google.com/p/k9mail/source/browse/k9mail/branches/activesync/src/com/android/email/mail/internet/WBXML.java?r=403)

```
namespaceURI = qName.substring(0, qName.lastIndexOf(":"));
```

qName.lastIndexOf(":") may return -1, means there's no ":" symbol in qName.

Comment: If I print it out using System.out.println(), I get this: is19 = java.io.FileInputStream@799ec4b6.   But, if I add this:   InputStream is19 = new FileInputStream(file19);
  
  InputStreamReader isr19 = new InputStreamReader( is19 );
  StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr19);
  String read = br.readLine();

  while(read != null) {

      sb.append(read);
      read =br.readLine();

  }

  System.out.println( "sb = " + sb );  Then, I can see the xml.  It looks ok.  There are spaces in between the tags.  But, I thought that did not matter in xml.

Comment: You should print a content, not the variable reference. Check this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8835/java-most-compact-way-to-print-inputstream-to-system-out

Comment: Show us the XML wich looks OK.

Comment: I just saw that post, here was the xml:  <?xml version="1.0"?><Device> <Owner>1</Owner></Device>

Comment: Your answer is 100% right.  I debugged further and got to that line and there is an error.  qName = "someCommand" and localName = "" at this point.  There is no ":" present.  Therefore, namespaceURI cannot be assigned a substring of qName because the length is not known since there is no ":" to mark the end of the substring.

Comment: Nice to hear this helped you ;)